# Symfony2 - Doctrine - Entity relationship between 2 bundles

Tags: php, doctrine, entity, symfony

I can't figure out how i can have an entity relationship between 2 bundles.

The closest i've been to succeed so far is this:

**User Entity**:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\AuthBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\generatedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\NewsBundle\Entity\Article", mappedBy="author")
     */
    protected $articles;


    //...
```

**Article Entity**:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\NewsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\NewsBundle\Entity\ArticleRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\AuthBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="articles")
     */
     protected $author;

     //...
```

When generating entities and updating the database, i get no errors and the relation is correctly set in the DB.

But when I try to fetch the articles i get this:

```
Class Acme\AuthBundle\Entity\Article does not exist
500 Internal Server Error - ReflectionException
```

Note that the User entity is in AuthBundle and Article entity in NewsBundle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the name of entity class when defining one-to-many, many-to-one relations. Still you are specifying `Acme\AuthBundle\Entity\User` not `Aief\AuthBundle\Entity\User` as `targetEntity`.

The same for Article and Article repository.

Comment: Oh sorry, typo error, I actually changed Aief to Acme just for the post (i'll edit that). So that's not it.

Comment: The problem is that it's looking for the Article Entity in the AuthBundle when it should be looking in the NewsBundle. I don't understand why.

Comment: Do you use any cache for Doctrine currently? Try cleaning it. Remove generated proxy classes as well, those can contain the wrong class name as well.

Comment: Nope that's not it, the cache for doctrine is empty.

Comment: Another note: When i fetch Users i don't get the error. Only when i fetch Articles.

Comment: Could you post full configuration of Doctrine?

Comment: I'm pretty new to SF2, how do i give you that? Do you mean what there is in config.yml?

Comment: Not familiar with configuration of Symfony. Can you give full trace of the Exception you're getting?

Comment: @TobiasHourst let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1046/discussion-between-gedrox-and-tobias-hourst)