# Same table, different mappings (Doctrine)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my site I have a `BlogBundle` and a `CMSBundle`. I need for both of these bundles to have entities with relationships with a `User` entity. For example, a `Comment` is written by a user, and a `Page` is created by a user.

I don't know how to achieve this because...

- I don't want to use just one entity as I'd have to declare the inverse side of all the relationships there, and I would end with dozens of unrelated properties in the `User` class
- I can't create two `User` entities mapped to the same table as Doctrine throws an exception complaining about this situation.
- I can't use inheritance mapping as I want to be able to use all the rows of the user table for all the relationships, and the single table inheritance forces you to indicate a discriminator column to load just the ones with the specified value for that relationship. I tried using the same value for this column but it only works with 2 entries in the `DiscriminatorMap`

Comment: Any success solving this? I want to achieve something similar.

Answer (score -1):

here is some Information about this: 
[Symfony2 - Doctrine - Entity relationship between 2 bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545072/symfony2-doctrine-entity-relationship-between-2-bundles)

Question is marked as solved there.

Comment: Thank you @mblaettermann but that question is about creating a relationship between an entity and another one which is located in another bundle. That's not my problem. The problem is, what happens when you have SEVERAL entities from SEVERAL bundles trying to use the same entity? Do you have to add the inverse side of the all those relationships to that entity? Because it doesn't feel right